# Cannot generate .pem from new .jks file

Tags: java, android, pem, huawei-developers, jks

I want to upload a new app to Huawei App Gallery. To do so, you have to upload a .pem file. According to documentation from Android and Huawei, this is done like so:

```
keytool -export -rfc -keystore upload-keystore.jks -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem
```

However, when I try and doo this on my brand new .jks file generated using Android Studio, I get:
"keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format"

It works fine on other, older, .jks files though.

I have no idea what to do. The best I can find is that 'Android Studio now runs on JDK 11'; but I don't know why that would make the jks unreadable for the keytool.

I've tried:

- Updating Java on my Mac (Java 8, Update 291)
- Updating to the latest android studio (Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1)

UPDATE:
As recommended by Robert, I downloaded keystore-explorer and saw that the '.jks' is actually a .p12 file. [image]

Will investigate and update as soon as I figure out how to get the .pem out of it.

Comment: Are you sure the file is a JavakeyStore file and not a PKCS#12 (.p12) file? Since about a year Java 11+ encrypts PKCS#12 files now with AES instead of 3DES. Older versions of Java only can decrypt such files if 3DES is used. I would try to open the file using https://keystore-explorer.org using the version with integrated JRE. It will display what file type the file is.

Comment: Hi @Robert! I downloaded keystore explorer and opened the file. It is indeed a PKCS#12 file, but I followed the steps to make the file as documented here https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release... where they tell you to use .jks in the file name.  Ill update my question to reflect all this then go have a look on how to get .pem from a .p12!

Comment: If you have opened the file in KeystoreExplorer can simply change the keystore type and save it as JKS file. Then file extension and content matches you your command should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use KeysTore Explorer it does all the tricky staff for you.

[image: Keystore Explorer]

It's free and helps a lot

https://keystore-explorer.org/

Answer (score 1):

As Robert pointed out, Android studio now generates a .p12 file (even if you give it a jks extension like in the documentation).

To generate a .prem, you can do:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.jks -out filename.pem -nodes
```

where filename.jks is actually a .p12 file.